# onClick button sum columns items in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

every time onclick button is not sum all item in the columns it's just minus 1 item from the loop `DtaGridAddInvBackBill.Items.Count - 1` when i try to remove `- 1` it's get in error on the `decimal sum +=`
all i need to every time click add the item then sum the last column `Inv ItemTotal` then after sum put in the Textblock `TotalItemcount`

```
decimal sum = 0m;
for (int i = 0; i < DtaGridAddInvBackBill.Items.Count - 1;i++)
{
    sum += (decimal.Parse((DtaGridAddInvBackBill.Columns[10].GetCellContent(DtaGridAddInBackBill.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text));
}
TotalItemcount.Text = " Invoice Total : ( " + Math.Round(sum, 2).ToString() + " )";
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have that `-1`. If it gives an error you should provide the error in your question so that we can help you solve the actual problem.

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=RestPOS
  StackTrace:
       at AppName.Items.Stock_List.AddNewBackItem_btn(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in e:\AppFolderr\App_Source_code\AppName\Items\Stock_List.xaml.cs:line 1060`

Comment: that the error i go when remove `- 1`

Comment: `(DtaGridAddInvBackBill.Columns[10].GetCellContent(DtaGridAddInBackBill.Items[i]) as TextBlock` will return `null` if `DtaGridAddInvBackBill.Columns[10].GetCellContent(DtaGridAddInBackBill.Items[i])` can't be cast to `TextBlock`

Comment: @john i got you , so what do you think is it better way to handle that ?

Comment: I mean that the particular item is possibly not a TextBlock

Comment: Please add any updates you have for the question, to the question instead of in a comment.

Comment: i did not found way to handle that yet in real if you can fix so thanks you @MarkusDeibel

Comment: The "edit" button is in the bottom left corner of the entry.

Comment: can you help me with this ? to fix my code please ?